# SVG fill full area

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have this svg code:

```html
<svg width="175" height="50" viewBox="0 0 175 80" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="black"><defs><linearGradient id="react-trend-vertical-gradient-8293353759684485" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="5%" y2="100%"><stop offset="50" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop><stop offset="10" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop></linearGradient></defs><path id="react-trend-8293353759684485" d="M 8,42
L 13.678571428571429,38.6
S 19.357142857142858,35.2 24.281343889820903,30.77751001593444
L 25.035714285714285,30.1
S 30.714285714285715,25 35.6065903546044,19.141542116247308
L 36.39285714285714,18.2
S 42.07142857142857,11.399999999999999 47.75,18.199999999999996
L 47.75,18.2
S 53.42857142857143,25 58.349935306257734,17.63343017050729
L 59.23065242856076,16.31512403775182
S 64.78571428571428,8 69.09240847758271,17.025097514028683
L 73.2924185202937,25.826627993470822
S 76.14285714285714,31.8 81.82142857142857,28.4
L 81.82142857142857,28.4
S 87.5,25 91.1766861455491,30.50346731220556
L 95.70266130254497,37.278197421419506
S 98.85714285714286,42 104.53571428571428,42
L 104.53571428571428,42
S 110.21428571428571,42 115.65431145502691,40.37141367761458
L 115.89285714285714,40.3
S 121.57142857142857,38.6 124.1242548742628,33.250303621985125
L 128.621877236703,23.82509751402868
S 132.92857142857144,14.8 137.792791259808,23.537240149692863
L 139.4214944544777,26.46275985030714
S 144.28571428571428,35.2 148.5924084775827,26.174902485971316
L 151.3361629509887,20.425097514028685
S 155.64285714285714,11.399999999999999 159.1224146222211,20.775109585908968
L 167,42" fill="#316BBE" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke="url(#react-trend-vertical-gradient-8293353759684485)"></path></svg>
```

Which produces this:
[image]

How do I get the fill to cover the full area at the bottom? As seen in the image, the width of the line seems to be extending beyond the fill area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered cutting off (clipping) the bottom part?

Pretty much copying from [MDN: Clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) (any errors are of my own making):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="175" height="50" viewBox="0 0 175 80" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="black">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="react-trend-vertical-gradient-8293353759684485" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="5%" y2="100%">
  <stop offset="50" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop>
  <stop offset="10" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop>
 </linearGradient>

    <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
      <rect x="0" y="-8" width="175" height="50"></rect>
    </clipPath>

</defs>
<path id="react-trend-8293353759684485" d="M 8,42
L 13.678571428571429,38.6
S 19.357142857142858,35.2 24.281343889820903,30.77751001593444
L 25.035714285714285,30.1
S 30.714285714285715,25 35.6065903546044,19.141542116247308
L 36.39285714285714,18.2
S 42.07142857142857,11.399999999999999 47.75,18.199999999999996
L 47.75,18.2
S 53.42857142857143,25 58.349935306257734,17.63343017050729
L 59.23065242856076,16.31512403775182
S 64.78571428571428,8 69.09240847758271,17.025097514028683
L 73.2924185202937,25.826627993470822
S 76.14285714285714,31.8 81.82142857142857,28.4
L 81.82142857142857,28.4
S 87.5,25 91.1766861455491,30.50346731220556
L 95.70266130254497,37.278197421419506
S 98.85714285714286,42 104.53571428571428,42
L 104.53571428571428,42
S 110.21428571428571,42 115.65431145502691,40.37141367761458
L 115.89285714285714,40.3
S 121.57142857142857,38.6 124.1242548742628,33.250303621985125
L 128.621877236703,23.82509751402868
S 132.92857142857144,14.8 137.792791259808,23.537240149692863
L 139.4214944544777,26.46275985030714
S 144.28571428571428,35.2 148.5924084775827,26.174902485971316
L 151.3361629509887,20.425097514028685
S 155.64285714285714,11.399999999999999 159.1224146222211,20.775109585908968
L 167,42" fill="#316BBE" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke="url(#react-trend-vertical-gradient-8293353759684485)"
 clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)">
</path>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]